# Sync Services: Tracking has cleaned up tracking information

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using Sync Services in a C# application. When my client syncs after a long wait, they are told that tracking info is gone and to re-init the database.

I can re-init, but what if the client has data that needs to be sent to the server? In this case, it's going to be lost. Is there any graceful solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get this error, you can change your synchronization type in code to upload only, then resync.

Then, when successful, drop your local table and download again, following your reinitialization.

You need to consider the time that the server is storing changes for. My rule of thumb is at least double the expected disconnect time.

Shout if you need more on this..